# How to run a cronjob after every 5minutes

Tags: cron

I've tried to run a cronjob like this:

`30/5 13-14 * * * ....`

i.e I want to run the cron every 5minutes from 1:30PM to 2:30PM.

But it doesn't seems to work.
Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use this syntax:

`*/5 * * * * .....`

But, the described situation needs to split the crontab entries in two:

`30,35,40,45,50,55 13 * * *  /your_job

0,5,10,15,20,25,30 14 * * * /your_job`

**Little more info:**

The crontab looks like this:

`(minutes) (hours) (day of month) (month) (day of week) (command)`

Also you can use range of numbers (ex. 8-11) or list (ex. 1,2,5,10). More info you can find typing:
 `info crontab`
In terminal.

Comment: I want to run the cron job from 1:30PM to 2:30PM after every 5minutes in between.

Comment: See the edited post for your case.

Comment: Isn't there any shorter code to work with?

Comment: I'm afraid this is the most self explicit method.